# how do OpenCV shared libraries in matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

i'm using matlab 2013a (win7 64bit).

install opencv on C:\OpenCV-2.4.7

how we connect Open Cv libraries into MATLAB's ?

Quick start -->

http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/calvin/calvin_upperbody_detector/downloads/README.html

e.g.

```
    from the bash command line execute:

    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="path_to_opencv_lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv). It easy to use and well documented. But if you want to get the real OpenCV MATLAB wrapper, you can only get it from the GitHub and not with the .exe

The [OpenCV Matlab module](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/modules/matlab)

Comment: For now, the official MATLAB wrapper is only available in the dev version. It will be released along with OpenCV 3.0: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/roadmap

Comment: Yep, still can get it from the gitHub module. But it a beta version. Mexopencv is good but not complete.