# How to convert opencv functions to mexopencv functions useable in matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv, video-tracking

My Problem:

I want to use functions of opencv like the MIL-Tracker or MedianFlow-Tracker in Matlab (these functions are not in mexopencv). But I don't know how or understand how to do this. The documentation of opencv/mexopencv doesn't help me. This doesn't help: [how do OpenCV shared libraries in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502206/how-do-opencv-shared-libraries-in-matlab) - because the link in the answer is down.

So is there a way to use these functions in Matlab? And if- How?

Why?: As a part of my bachelor thesis I have to compare different already implemented ways to track people.

Comment: I updated one of the broken links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to use these functions specifically in MATLAB you could always write your own MEX file in C/C++ and send the data back/forward between the two calls, however this would require some basic C++ knowledge and understanding creating MEX files.

Personally I would definately recommend trying this with Python and the OpenCV Python interface since its so widely used and more supported than using the calls in MATLAB (plus its always a useful skill to be able to switch between Python and MATLAB as and when needed).

There is a full example with the MIL-Tracker and the MedianFlow-Tracker (and others) [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/) (Which demonstrates using them in C++ and Python!).

---

**Python Example :**

```
import cv2
import sys

(major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')￼

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Set up tracker.
    # Instead of MIL, you can also use

    tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN']
    tracker_type = tracker_types[2]

    if int(minor_ver) < 3:
        tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
    else:
        if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MIL':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        if tracker_type == 'KCF':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        if tracker_type == 'TLD':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()

    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/chaplin.mp4")

    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print "Could not open video"
        sys.exit()

    # Read first frame.
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        print 'Cannot read video file'
        sys.exit()

    # Define an initial bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

    while True:
        # Read a new frame
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            break

        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);

        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

        # Exit if ESC pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27 : break
```

---

I would definately try it using Python (if this is an option). Otherwise if MATLAB is a must then probably try implementing the C++ example code shown in the link [before](https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/) as a [MEX file](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html) and linking openCV during the compilation i.e.

```
mex trackerMexOpenCV.cpp 'true filepath location to openCV lib'
```

I hope this helps!